# Can I use an aux cable with inline volume controls with Android? Want EarPods inline volume controls to work

Tags: iphone, audio, headphones, android

Sorry for the super long title. I just wanted to make myself clear.

I want to forgo the EarPods' built-in inline volume controls, play/pause button and mic, and transfer those over to an aux cable with inline controls.

I would connect this aux cable to my Android phone and be able to control volume, playback, and use the microphone without issue.

Is this possible? I've never heard of anyone trying it before, so I'm curious. I'm rather attached to my EarPods and would like to use them fully with Android. Haven't found a adapter that supports the EarPods' native volume controls on Android, and I suppose I never will. Right now only the EarPods' play/pause button and mic are working with my Android 6.0.1 phone.

I know Apple uses that proprietary TRRS standard. But there are aux cables out there that support both Android and iOS inline controls (Bose and MEE audio seem to offer replacement aux cables with all inline controls compatible with both OSes). Surely those would let me do what I'm trying to do.

Any input? Thanks!